# Right shift in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Want to get equivalent python conversion for the following java code.

```
msg = "any text"
int len = msg == null ? 0 : msg.length ();
if (len > 0) {
    byte lb[] = new byte[4];
    lb[3] = (byte) (len & 0xFF);
    lb[2] = (byte) ((len >> 8) & 0xFF);
    lb[1] = (byte) ((len >> 16) & 0xFF);
    lb[0] = (byte) ((len >> 24) & 0xFF); 
}
```

Please help.

Comment: SO is not a free code translation service. If you want help with this you need to post your attempt at coding this in Python, and clearly describe what's stopping you from completing the task. FWIW, you can use the bitwise `&` and `>>` operators in Python. To get you started, you can implement the 2nd line as `len = len(msg) if msg else 0`

Comment: Do you want to implement this exact algorithm in Python? Or do you just want code that produces an equivalent answer? In Python 3, you can easily do this operation by calling the `int.to_bytes` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg   = "any text"
length = 0 if msg is None else len(msg)
if length > 0:
    lb    = []
    lb.append((length >> 24) & 0xFF)
    lb.append((length >> 16) & 0xFF)
    lb.append((length >> 8) & 0xFF)
    lb.append((length     ) & 0xFF)

newmsg = b''.join(chr(i) for i in lb)
```

Comment: Who has downvoted this answer ? Specify the reason, for downvoting.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: can I use it as bytes(lb.append(bytes((length >> 24) & 0xFF))) ?? Getting error "TypeError: an integer is required". Sorry but I am very new to Python and learning from the basics, so please ignore all silly questions.

Comment: I think, it'll not accomplish, what you want to accomplish in your java code. Moreover, running code given by you, is not giving any error at my end. So want to know, which python version are you using ?

Comment: I need to send some messages (name/value pair) to the gateway server and need to have a byte code as a prefix for that message. The code I have written above is the same byte code accepted by my gateway.

Comment: Refer to my updated answer. I think It may help you.

Comment: code provided returns values as an integer in array index. I am expecting a byte code value for each index of my array. For your example I am getting lb as (0,0,0,8) but I am expecting lb as (00000000,00000000,00000000,00000100).

Comment: Have you checked last line. It's actually returning you a byte array ?

Comment: I am getting some junk characters using that line. Using python 3.3.2.

Comment: Is it something like this '\x00\x00\x00\x08' ?

Comment: It is actually a "?" inside a sqare bracket and newmsg is having a value "\b" while debugging

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = "any text"
len =  len(msg)
lb = []
if len > 0 :
    lb.append(len & 0xFF)
    lb.append((len >> 8) & 0xFF)
    lb.append((len >> 16) & 0xFF)
    lb.append((len >> 24) & 0xFF)


for num in reversed(lb):
    print (num)
```